# IoC container that supports constructor injection with Scala named/default arguments?

Tags: scala, constructor, ioc-container, named-parameters

I would prefer using constructor injection over JavaBean property injection if I could utilize the named and default arguments feature of Scala 2.8. Any IoC-containers exists that supports that or could be easily extended to do so? (The required information is there on runtime in the `scala.reflect.ScalaSignature` annotation of the class.)

I also have some basic(?) expectations from the IoC container:

- Auto-wiring (by target class/trait or annotation, both one-to-one and one-to-many)
- Explicit injection (explicit wiring) without much hassle (like Guice is weak there). Like `user` is injected that way in `new ConnectionPool(user="test")`.
- Life-cycle callback for cleanup on shutdown (in the proper order)

Spring can do these, obviosuly, but it doesn't support named parameters. I have considered using `FactoryBean`-s to bridge Scala and Spring, but that would mean too much hassle (boilerplate or code generation), as far as I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PART A

I have a work-in-progress reflection library that parses the Scala signature and is currently able to resolve named parameters: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-reflect

Unfortunately, I haven't yet tied it back into Java reflection to be able to invoke methods, nor have I added the logic to resolve default values (though this *should* be trivial).  Both features are very high on my to-do list :)

This isn't an IoC container per-se, but it's a pre-requisite for another project of mine: https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-spring. Work on scalaj-spring stopped when it became blindingly obvious that I wouldn't be able to make any worthwhile further progress until I had signature-based reflection in place.

### PART B

All of that stuff is intended for big enterprisey people anyway.  Those with no choice but to integrate their shiny new Scala code into some hulking legacy system... If that's not your use case, then you can just do Scala DI directly inside Scala.

There's DI support provided under the Lift banner: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Dependency_Injection

You should also hunt around for references to the cake pattern

Comment: In Part B be are you suggesting that the cake pattern is replacement for IoC containers **in general** when there is no legacy system to integrate with? I would be a pessimistic regarding that. Cake doesn't provide life-cycle events (constructors are called in `val` order, not on the proper dependency order unless you are using `lazy var`-s), its auto-wiring capability is limited (like it can't do one-to-many wiring where the "one" side is a collection), etc. Surely it covers many use-cases where in Java you would use Spring or like, but all of them?

Comment: Lifestyle events arguably aren't part of dependency injection, though I do appreciate that it's often provided in conjunction. More generally, lifestyle events have no place in an immutable object graph anyway... You'll also find that Scala does the right thing when initializing singletons, another feature commonly delegated to Spring.

Comment: The "init" life-cycle event is needed even with immutable objects, and it's implemented by the constructor (assuming you have avoided property injection). But, cake doesn't order these initializations automatically (unless you are using `lazy val` for everything). So even if you declare that `foo` depends on `bar`, when the constructor of `foo` runs, `bar` can be still `null`.

Comment: Ideally, you'll set everything up to be a directed acyclic graph, then every object will be initialised before it's used elsewhere. If you really have no choice but to introduce a cycle - sometimes unavoidable - then you can "break" it by passing the dependency as a by-name param, and assigning this to a lazy val if necessary (as you already noted)

Comment: p.s. an object that goes through a 2-phase initialisation can't *ever* be considered immutable. Not if something must be changed post-construction.

Comment: It's off-topic at this point, but what I've talked about is that if I have `object Components extend FooComponent with BarComponent { val foo = new Foo; val bar = new Bar }` (`val foo` and `val bar` override the abstract `val`-s from `FooComponent` and `BarComponent`), and I have declared `FooComponent` to depend on `BarComponent` (as `trait FooComponent { self: BarComponent ... }`), the constructor of `Foo` will see a `bar` that's `null`. To fix that, I have to exchange the two `val`-s in the source code. Any reasonable IoC container should do this ordering automatically.

Comment: lazy vals will deal with that, as will defs, you may also be interested in exploring early initialiser syntax and Scala 2.9s DelayedInit trait

Answer (score 2):

Another dependency injection framework in Scala is [subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut)

Answer (score 1):

> I have considered using FactoryBean-s to bridge Scala and Spring, but that would mean too much hassle

I am not sure I understand the complexity. Its actually quite simple to implement Spring FactoryBeans in Scala. Check this little write-up http://olegzk.blogspot.com/2011/07/implementing-springs-factorybean-in.html

Comment: It's an extra boilerplate class for each of your normal classes, at least assuming that you have any constructor parameters there, which is what this question is about. Then for each constructor parameters you have to create a @BeanProperty, then pass their values to the constructor. This is all pure boilerplate that has 0 value, I mean, it could be 100% machine-generated.

Answer (score 1):

I've just released Sindi, an IoC container for the Scala programming language.

http://aloiscochard.github.com/sindi/